Remove xml element if subelements are empty or don't exist
I need to remove an xml element if both the subelements fiel1 and field2 don't exist or are blank.
Input and expected result (see comments)
<root><!-- document -->
  <element><!-- keep -->
    <field1>A</field1>
  </element>
  <element><!-- keep -->
    <field2>B</field2>
  </element>
  <element><!-- delete -->
    <field1/>
  </element>
  <element><!-- delete></element>
  <element/><!-- delete -->
</root>

non-working Xsl (v.1 required)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="field1 or field2">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Could anybody help please?
Thanks

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Please indent your code examples for easier reading.

This question is similar to: XSLT: How to exclude empty elements from my result?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A common approach to problems like this is to copy everything as is as the rule, with an empty template making an exception for the nodes you want to delete:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element[not(field1/text() or field2/text())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

In a simple case such as your example you could reduce this to:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="element[field1/text() or field2/text()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

